# Performance of the "SELECT WHERE WEEKDAY() = something" statement

Tags: mysql

A really simple question.
I have a table representing receipts with ~1M+ rows, and must filter/group it by the day of the week too.
For example: show me statistically what is the day of the week with more receipts emitted
and the one where people spend more money in total? and per receipt?

I know how to do it, my only concern regards performance.
I was thinking about adding an entirely new fiel "Day_of_the_week", but this way I have to modify and retest a lot of code.

So, WEEKDAY(Date_field) is faster/same than a dedicated field, or is better to rework the table?

Comment: I doubt that it can index that expression, so it will have to compute it for every row that's being selected. It will be expensive.

Comment: Though for only 14% selectivity a scan might be quicker than seeking a non covering index anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using weekday, the whole table is read, and the function is called for each row.
If you use a dedicated field with an index only the index is read.
So, the performance question is pretty clear.

But the query you describe seems to be an occasional analysis. I think the performance of such an occasional query should not dictate a refactoring of the code. With a special data drilling query some delay should be acceptable.